# "Come Baby Come" by K7 - lyrics for the female vocals?

Tags: lyrics, hip-hop

I am looking for the lyrics of the 90s song ["Come Baby Come"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8CUfVtrAT8) by [K7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K7_(musician)), but I cannot find one that includes the female vocals at the start of the song after the "Da ding de ding de ding" part. (I turned on the captions and the female part didn't show any captions.)

The only info I saw is that it is a [jazzy scat vocal by Camille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come_Baby_Come). Does anyone have the words/syllables for that part?

[Here](https://genius.com/K7-come-baby-come-lyrics) is a link to the lyrics (without the female vocals part).

Comment: Are you talking about https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8CUfVtrAT8 ? does this have the female vocal you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, the one after the "Da ding de ding de ding" part. I turned on the captions and the female part didn't show any captions.

Comment: Honestly I don't think those are words, it's like the la's and da's in some songs. It sounds like get it on or get it done but after I listen to it a few times, it just sounds like she is making noises that similar to the song's beat